What sources state that Lakshmi's blessings are attained only through action?
Recently a popular new mythological TV show (not a good source) based on Lakshmi and Vishnu has stated repeatedly that the blessings of Lakshmi can only be obtained through action, and not through desire or anything else.
I'm familiar with the verses of the Bhagavad Gita advising Arjuna to take action without seeking the fruit of the action. I'm also somewhat familiar with Lakshmi's emergence from the ocean of milk, and her choice to become consort to Vishnu because he did not desire anything from her.
But after some searching I haven't been able to find any texts specifically stating that Lakshmi's blessings, spiritual and/or material, are only attainable through action, and not through desire or other methods.
Does anyone know of a source for this?
(Note: I am asking not to criticize the TV show, but to find relevant materials so I can read more about this idea.)

Thank you for looking at this. If blessings of Lakshmi are obtained through worshipping Narayan and worshipping Narayan requires action (not desire, etc.) then I think that is a valid answer to this question. That idea isn't inconsistent with materials I'm aware of. The TV show is presenting this as more about obtaining Lakshmi's blessings directly (in fact it refers to Vishnu obtaining Lakshmi—a little odd because it was Lakshmi who chose Vishnu). It's possible the show is distorting things. In any case, I'm interested in all possibilities: seeking Lakshmi's blessings directly or indirectly.
